# how to make table names dynamic in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make the table name dynamic

```
declare @varString as nvarchar(10)
set @varString = '06232016'
declare @testString as nvarchar(500)
set @testString = 'SELECT  *  from ' +  'Cases_' + @varstring
execute sp_executesql @testString 
Select top 10 FROM @teststring
```

The first 5 lines of the code are working fine. Now how do I use the dynamic table name I just created? The last line is giving the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that is failing is:

```
Select top 10 FROM @teststring
```

a) You're missing the column names (or indeed *)

b) What you're trying to do is not possible unless you use dynamic SQL

You use it in the exact way you are already using it.

```
-- Declare Table Name
DECLARE @tablename AS nvarchar(10);
SET @tablename = 'MyTestTable';

-- Execute a query
DECLARE @query_a AS nvarchar(500);
SET @query_a  = 'SELECT TOP 10  * FROM dbo.' +  @tablename;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_a;

-- Execute another query
DECLARE @query_b AS nvarchar(500);
SET @query_b = 'UPDATE dbo.' + @tablename + ' SET col_a = ''xyz''';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_b;
```

Warning: If you are inputting the tablename from a GUI, you need to sanitise the data to avoid SQL Injection attacks (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

N.B. Use an `ORDER BY` when using `TOP`

Comment: @AmanSanganeria: Table names are not parametrisable in T-SQL. Dynamic SQL (shown in Mark's answer) is the only way to go when you want to make table names dynamic. From your description, however, it's not entirely clear why you have to use a different table every few days. If you used a single table with a dedicated date column to store the date of each day's dataset, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.